# Update Query On Database with LIKE %string% speed issues

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Alright, so I have two tables. One table has over 2 million rows (descriptions), another table has 35k rows (names). I'm trying to apply an id to the descriptions table based on the names table name that matches in the descriptions table. For example...

descriptions

```
id | info_text | name_id
 1 | this is information for John Doe living in Oregon
 2 | going to Wisconsin with Jane Doe next wednesday
```

names

```
id | name
 1 | John Doe
 2 | Jane Doe
```

So with that table set up I'm using this query...

```
$qry = "UPDATE descriptions t1, names t2 SET t1.name_id = t2.id 
          WHERE t1.info_text LIKE Concat('%',t2.name,'%')";
```

This takes over 5 minutes and the server goes away. I added a fulltext index to the info_text column but I've read that using LIKE %''% still does a full table scan. Is there any tricks or solutions to speeding up this process where I don't have to go through all the names in the names database one by one to update the 2 million rows in the descriptions table? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to use the `MATCH()` function to search the full-text index. Isn't this explained in the documentation?

Comment: You can't use full-text indexes to search for variable data, like joining between tables. The search string has to be a literal in the query.

Comment: Yea, I did the MATCH() also and it was actually slower than the LIKE.

Comment: So is there a solution @Barmar?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to optimize `LIKE '%string%'` well, it has to perform a full scan. One thing you can try is to break the table up into subsets.

```
$alphabet = array('a', 'b', ..., 'z');
foreach ($alphabet as $initial) {
    $qry = "UPDATE descriptions t1, names t2 SET t1.name_id = t2.id 
            WHERE t1.info_text LIKE '$initial%' AND t1.info_text LIKE Concat('%',t2.name,'%')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
}
```

Make sure you have an ordinary index on the `info_text` column. Then matching the first character with `LIKE` will be fast, and it will only have to scan the subset for the names.